# plotting vector equations with increasing variables on both axes python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, variables

i have been attempting a vector plot (by using quiver) in which every location on the grid is assigned a vector dependant on the location and equations but i am stuck on  trying to use a range of both axis parameters (x1 and x3), getting an error:**TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**

this is the code as built so far and any help would be amazing:

```
def SVmotion(t,A,beta,f,j):
    x1= np.arange(0,10001,100)
    x3= np.arange(0,10001,100)
    w=2*np.pi*f
    k=w/beta
    k1=k*np.sin(j)
    k3=k*np.cos(j)
    k_beta_x = k1*x1+k3*x3
    theta = k_beta_x-w*t
    Usvx1 = k3*A*complex(-np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta))
    Usvx3 = k1*A*complex(-np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta))
    Usvx1_real=Usvx1.real
    Usvx3_real=Usvx3.real

    return  Usvx1_real,  Usvx3_real

    fig ,ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.quiver(x1,x3,Usvx1_real,Usvx3_real)


SVmotion(0,1,3000,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that 'theta' is an array. Please check if the following helps.

```py
import numpy as np

def SVmotion(t,A,beta,f,j):
    x1= np.arange(0,10001,100)
    x3= np.arange(0,10001,100)
    w=2*np.pi*f
    k=w/beta
    k1=k*np.sin(j)
    k3=k*np.cos(j)
    k_beta_x = k1*x1+k3*x3
    theta = k_beta_x-w*t
    for t in theta:
        Usvx1 = k3*A*complex(-np.sin(t),np.cos(t))
        Usvx3 = k1*A*complex(-np.sin(t),np.cos(t))
        Usvx1_real=Usvx1.real
        Usvx3_real=Usvx3.real   

    return  Usvx1_real,  Usvx3_real

SVmotion(0,1,3000,2,0)
#(0.003627598728468422, 0.0)
```

Comment: t is used as a specific number, and substituting it inside sin() and cos() does not serve the purpose and completely alters the equation, the problem lies specifically with the ranges of x1 and x3 (which determine the location of the vector), i am able to do this using another plot function for 1 altering variable(representing an axis) but not for 2